# Is this the correct preposition? "He has updated the reporting relationship of this position number in the database."

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

"He has updated the reporting relationship of this position number in the database."

Q: Is "of" the correct preposition to use? Or, should "for" be used instead?

Comment: Maybe give a specific example, because it sounds to me unclear, as well as redundant.  Is he simply changing a Netflix queue 10th item to the 1st, or changing a database table record (with multiple one-to-many linked relational tables) from the “Marketing” Department to “Sales” – so the entire report Form changes, frequency, audience, etc. - by changing that one database field value?  “report relationship” and “position number” need to be defined, for me to help anyway.

Comment: Hi "ipso". Thanks for responding. Okay, let me break the sentence down. The database consists of information about, let's say, jobs and their respective departments. The job, Executive Assistant A, used to be part of the Marketing department. Joe made some changes in the database. End result: the job, Executive Assistant A, is now part of the Sales department instead. What's the best way to say all that in a single sentence?

Comment: *“Joe updated the database to reflect the position change.”*  : )

Comment: "of" sounds fine and is basically interchangeable with "**'s**". Verify this with the following equivalent statements: "The reporting relationship **of** the position number is X." (= "The position **number's** reporting relationship is X."

Comment: What is the connection between the reporting relationship and the change in data on job positions or departments. Reporting is the process of preparing reports and submitting them to the superior authority. I am curious about what the reporting relationship means in this context. Is it a valid "term" or just bad translation?

Comment: Thanks, "Brandin", for clarifying. That makes sense! :-)

Comment: Hi "Amande douce". I'll explain it in a different way. For example, John supervises Jane. John is Jane's immediate supervisor, and Jane is John's direct report. Jane, who is Executive Assistant A, reports to John, VP of Marketing. That is the reporting relationship for the job, Executive Assistant A. Each job is assigned a specific position number. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say, in communications to non- IT people:

"Updated the database to reflect that {Executive Assistant A [Name]} is now reporting to {Title Name}."

And to IT people : "changed Position #xxx (Executive Assistant A) to report to Position #yyy in the DDD table."

(FYI: I am a technical writer for an Information Technology department in an American company, but am not a database specialist.)

Comment: Thank you, Brian Hitchcock! That was very helpful! Much appreciated! :-)